# Is there a meaningful definition of $\lim_{f(x)\to a}g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, notation, definition

Fairly often, I have seen the notation $\lim_{f(x)\to a}g(x)$ being used in the context of evaluating limits, e.g.
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}=\lim_{2x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}\overset{y=2x}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1 \, .
$$
While the meaning of such equations is clear enough, I consider this to be a mild abuse of notation for the following reason: when we write $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$, the variable $x$ is bound by the limit operator; however, only single-letter variables such as $x$ and $y$ can be bound, not arbitrary algebraic expressions such as $2x$. So is there a formal definition of $\lim_{f(x)\to a}g(x)=l$ that avoids this problem? Perhaps we say that $\lim_{f(x)\to a}g(x)=l$ if $a$ is an accumulation point of $\operatorname{dom}(g)\cap\operatorname{ran}(f)$, and
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)\cap\operatorname{ran}(f):0<|f(x)-a|<\delta\implies |g(x)-l|<\varepsilon \, .
$$

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly reasonable definition. I'd do it the same way.

Comment: If $f$ is a homeomorphism on a neighborhood of an element of $f^{-1}(\{ a \})$ then I think the natural meaning of $\lim_{f(x) \to a}$ is just $\lim_{x \to f^{-1}(a)}$ (where $f^{-1}$ might only be a local inverse). This is less restrictive than your version if $f$ isn't a global homeomorphism since you don't force "far away $x$'s" to matter. That said usually in such a substitution you would pick a global homeomorphism anyway.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831604/limit-of-composite-functions) might help.

Comment: The limit law for composite functions will provide an explanation to this, but the idea of defining a new type of limit sounds interesting to me. I also think that your notion of limit can be absorbed to a special case of a much well-known concept (such as [limit of filter in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology)).

Comment: Why isn't $\ 2x\to a\ $ "obviously" the same thing as $\ x\to \frac{a}{2}\ $ ?

Comment: I think you want $\forall x\in \mathrm{dom}(g)\cap \mathrm{dom}(f)$.